# The Opposite of Fitts' Law

Tags: discussion, user-interface

Jeff recently blogged about [The Opposite of Fitts' Law](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-opposite-of-fitts-law/) about how some dangerous elements are close to useful ones and how they are the same size.

He was talking about flaws in the GMail interface but the same happens on SO as well. "link", "edit", and "delete" are all on the same line. As "delete" is the largest of them, it is the most dangerous one.

Especially considering the fact that mere mortals with less then 10K rep can't undelete their own post once they leave the page, as there's no way to find that post to undelete.

So, Jeff, will you stand behind your ideas and redesign SO in accordance with them?

Comment: So you don't get the prompt warning you?

Comment: @random, funny thing, I don't actually remember :) I must have pressed enter immediately those few times I've actually deleted something.

Answer (score 4):

Aren't all those options that you mentioned sort of secondary tasks that are relatively hard to press (text links instead of icons or buttons) as well being located roughly in the middle of the screen?

Answer (score 4):

There's no ejector seat there.

Delete actually has a JavaScript confirmation dialog, and clicking "edit" doesn't do anything bad..

Compare with clicking "SEND EMAIL!" which is effectively unrecoverable. (Yes, I know there is a labs function, but it's not a default -- should be though.)

Comment: Oh, well, I've deleted few posts and the fact that I couldn't even remember there was message box is kind of supporting the idea that those are so common, they become invisible. It's almost a reflex now to press enter every time something pops at you. So, it's not a good guardian. And as I said, 'delete' is only recoverable if you have enough reputation to see you post again.

Comment: @vava you can undelete any post you can delete .. and those you can't (those that are protected because they have value to others) require multiple votes to be deleted.

Comment: yes, I can undelete it. **BUT** I can't see it. I literally have no way of seeing it since I do not have enough rep. And since I can't see it, I can't click on 'undelete' button.
So I can undelete only before I leave the page with deleted post. And accidentally closing the tab or browser is even easier than clicking that 'delete' link.

Comment: @vava "I can undelete only before I leave the page with deleted post" this seems sufficient to me..